# making "xwacom set" changes permanent

Tags: touchscreen, wacom

On my Thinkpad X220 Tablet the touch-finger works flawlessly but the pen is terribly miscalibrated. The calibration tool in System settings -> Wacom tablet does not work. Instead, whenever I wan't to use the pen I first need to

```
sudo xsetwacom set 'Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen stylus' Area 0 0 27760 15690
```

These changes do not remain permanent. That is, after every reboot they are gone. How can I make the change permanent - I'm not looking for a startup scrip, I'd like to set the right area once for all. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Save a file ending in `.conf` with the following content in your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Wacom Area configurations"
    # Match all Wacom input tools that have "BambooFun 6x8" in the "device name".
    MatchProduct "Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen stylus"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"

    # Apply a custom configuration options. Any option will also apply to
    # all dependent devices, if applicable. So e.g. the pressure curve will
    # be available on the stylus and the eraser (but not on the pad).
    Option "Area" "0 0 27760 15690"
EndSection
```

The option part isn't the same for both Xorg and xsetwacom, so it would need you to check it out.

Source http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Xorg.conf.d

Comment: looks absolutely reasonable, however, does not work. The pen is calibrated in the guest account and at the log-in screen. As soon as I log in to my account, the cursor "jumps" away from the pen and is miscalibrated. I guess some config file must be loaded with my profile but I simply can't figure out where that file resides?

Comment: If you create a new account the problem happens?